# Cannot connect to remote SQL Server instance from app in container

Tags: docker, nservicebus, windows-container

Pretty new to docker, but I just created an image and it seems to start up fine until it attempts to connect to a remote SQL server. That is, a SQL server that is on it's own VM and is normally accessible via a host (e.g. mydatabase.mydomain.com). This problem doesn't present when it's run out of visual studio; the database is fine and it is reachable.

I suspect that it has something with docker networking. I tried exposing 1433 with no luck. I've also tried running it with `--net=host` also no luck. The errors are being output by NServiceBus where it's trying to communiciate with AzureServiceBus as well as SQL Server stating that the server was not responding or is unreachable.

The Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
WORKDIR /command
EXPOSE 8002
EXPOSE 1433
COPY . /command
ENTRYPOINT ["NServiceBus.Host.exe"]
```

Any ideas or insight would be good.

Comment: Downvoter, I appreciate your insight and close request. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a firewall issue on SQL Server host.

[Here](http://passionatecoder.ca/Article/Deploying-ASPNET-and-SQL-SERVER-application-using-Windows-Containers-on-Azure) is an article on how to host a multi container application on a windows container.